# Sending Email with custom header,footer

Tags: magento2, email, template

I want to create a custom header and footer for email templates.
currently when the user receives an email the logo in the head redirects it to the store URL but I want it to redirect to somewhere else i.e custom URL from configuration

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
```

instead of the above line, I want to add my custom header

```
  {{template config_path="path/to/custom_header"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to create custom header and footer for email templates.

> Step 1:- Go to admin panel > Marketing > Email Templates > Add new
> template

```
For Header :- 

- Select "Header" template from dropdown(default template lists) and load selected template
- Add "Template Name" as per you want. Here are we are adding like "Custom header"

Please see screen shot for more info - https://prnt.sc/1q4qirg

For Footer :-

- Select "Footer" template from dropdown(default template lists) and load selected template
- Add "Template Name" as per you want. Here are we are adding like "Custom footer"

Please see screen shot for more info - https://prnt.sc/1q4qwm6
```

> Step 2 :- Please go to Content > Design > Configuration > Edit your
> current theme

```
- Now do scroll down , you will see "Transactional Emails" section.
- From there you need to select custom created "Header" and "Footer" Template from the dropdown list (https://prnt.sc/1q4rx5w)
```

Now your custom header and footer will call for all your email templates.

Cheers!